# Update legend entry in for loop using fig.add_trace using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I'm updating a violin plot with new traces using `plotly` go. However, I can't seem to figure out how to update the names of the different traces as they are added to the figure. All I get now are "trace 1", "trace 2", etc.

How can this be done? I suppose the answer is simple but I'm kind of new to this so any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
from plotly.colors import n_colors

colors = n_colors('rgb(2, 200, 200)', 'rgb(300, 10, 10)', 12, colortype='rgb')

fig = go.Figure()
for data_line, color in zip(hist_data, colors):
    fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color))

fig.update_traces(orientation='h', side='positive', width=3, points=False)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=False, xaxis_zeroline=True)
```

I tried adding the name handle to fig.add_trace and calling a list of names, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` kwarg to set the name of the trace, which will be used to label the relevant entry in the legend.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=data_line, line_color=color, name="<trace_name>"))
```

https://plotly.com/python/reference/violin/#violin-name

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I want to add it to a for loop? It appears to me as if it only allows strings, not a list with strings (which in this case is exactly what I need)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you should only want to assign one string to each trace? If that is the case, just zip the list of strings where you are already (in instantiating your `for` loop), and add to the unpacking as `for ..., ..., name in ...:`